# Export to PowerPoint (.PPT)

Tags: php, html, xml, powerpoint

How can HTML/XML/JSON data be exported to PowerPoint format using PHP? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to assume that everybody knows what "ppt" is. I guess you mean PowerPoint, so I fixed this for you.

Comment: OregonGhost... you have edited out .ppt in favour of PowerPoint, but what if he wants a .ppt and not a .pptx for the newer 2007 format?

Comment: Then it should be PowerPoint 2003 explicitly, and not .ppt. It's still in the title though.

Comment: I've been looking for something similar and found this.
http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home
I haven't started playing with it yet, though, so I can't really vouch for it.

Comment: .ppt is an standard, you dont add any value with you correction @OregonGhost

Answer (score 1):

As of PowerPoint 2007, documents can be saved and editied as XML.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739834.aspx for reference.

I am not aware of any PHP libraries that offer an interface for the creation of ppt files. Therefore, your best bet is probably [DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is by finding a commandline program that does the conversion. Then you can call the commandline program with [shell_exec](http://php.net/shell_exec).

However, I don't know any program at all that does what you want. Maybe you can do it with OpenOffice.org Impress in headless mode?